# Android Facebook Login "LoginActivity could not be started"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have installed and configure everything for link The Facebook SDK to my Android App.

- Facebook SDK is in my project
- I added my APP ID in the Facebook APP ID
- My Android Key Hash is correct and linked on the board of Facebook Dev
- I have the Activity "com.facebook.FacebookActivity" in my Manifest
- I have the Activity "com.facebook.LoginActivity" in my Manifest
- I have the meta-data facebook_app_id set in my Manifest and correct

The Facebook widget Login set

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

My Fragment Class

```
public class FragmentSetting extends  android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    SingletonUserData.setCallbackManager(CallbackManager.Factory.create());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {
    if (!SingletonUserData.isLogged()) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logme, container, false);
        TextView facebook = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.LogByFacebook);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(SingletonUserData.getCallbackManager(), new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {...});
```

and

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    SingletonUserData.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After several hours, I can't find the error.
Is it because of the Fragment? I tried in my MainActivityToFragment but I have always the same backtrace, which is:

> Log in attempt failed: LoginActivity could not be started
> at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:382)
> at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:250)
> at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(LoginButton.java:689)
> at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase$1.onClick(FacebookButtonBase.java:310)

Comment: You added facebookactivity to your manifest but did you add loginactivity to your manifest?

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, Yes i did

Comment: Did you find a work around?

Comment: Still working on it, but always the same issue

Comment: Well it's an old post but did you have the standard Facebook app installed on the test device?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing LoginActivity from my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--Remove this-->
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and adding

```
<!--Add this-->
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
 android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Saved my job 

Comment: There is too many errors in integrating facebook. I have to start documenting all these fixes DONATO.

Answer (score 2):

So I had the same issue and fixed it by... setting up my app properly on the [Facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Basically my app was missing:

- (Google Play) package name
- class name
- a key hash

Once I fill these in, the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Hash Key of the under-developing app and facebook a/c will ask hash key both should be same.

```
public void getHashkey(){
 try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                Log.e("Name not found", e1.toString());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                Log.e("No such an algorithm", e.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
}
```

call this in your onCreate() of Activity and copy that hash key (which will end with = sign) from log and just register into facebook a/c and u are done.